# How to avoid this async lazy pattern?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Many times, I needed to write such a lazy asynchronous loading in Javascript:

```
if (myvar != undefined){
    doSomeTreatment(myvar)
} else {
    loadMyVarAsynchronously().then(function(value){
        myvar = value
        doSomeTreatment(myvar)
    })
}
```

Here, myvar would be some attribute of a hash, not a local variable. `loadMyVarAsynchronously` loads asynchronously the value for myvar (with, for example, a `Promise` or a `JQuery Deferred`)

Is there a pattern to avoid having to write twice the following line in this code?

```
doSomeTreatment(myvar)
```

Comment: oops - are these jQuery promises or new "standard" promises?

Comment: My question is wanted to be agnostic, so that the answer can propose the best solution! So just use the best standard or not Promise, or Deferred, or anything else you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to reason about what you are doing here without a concrete, real-world example. This is definitely not a pattern I use a lot in my code so I have a suspicion that you could go around fixing it by re-assessing your assumptions.

That being said, you can use promise chaining. Note in this case promiseThatLoadsVar IS a promise, it's not a function that returns a promise. That means it maintains a state, and the second time this code runs onward it will return immediately.

```
promisethatLoadsVar.then(function(value) {
     myvar = value;
     doSomeTreatment(myvar);
})
```

If you could give a clearer question I'd love to provide a clearer answer for you.

**Edit**: I want to elaborate on the example posed in the comments. Here is a solution using the [LoDash](https://lodash.com/) library. (BTW, you should use lodash or underscore, they are basically the standard library of javascript).

```
var getData = _.once(function() { return $.getJSON(...) });

$('button').on('click', function() { 
    getData().then(function(data) { showDialog(data) }) 
})
```

Note here that `getData` is a wrapped function that after the first invocation will just return the same thing over and over without re-invoking the function. The first time you invoke it, it will return a promise that resolves when data is retrieved. The second time onward you get back *the same promise* which will likely already be resolved.

Do you want to pass in parameters to `getData`?

```
var getData = _.memoize(function(id) { return $.getJSON(url+id) });

$('button').on('click', function() { 
    getData($('#selector').val()).then(function(data) { showDialog(data) }) 
})
```

This will do the same thing, but cache the promises by the first input parameter passed to `getData`.

Comment: I'm really surprised you tell me this is not a useful pattern. This is a very classical way of lazy loading, with in bonus the asynchronous parameter. This is, IMHO, a pretty good optimisation in term of performance and in GUI reactivity.

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe I'm not saying it's not a useful pattern, but perhaps the ways I design UI architecture and the libraries I use (I'm a big fan of knockout and ReactJs) do things in such a way as to make this usually unnecessary. I of course do not load all data up-front but it is extremely rare that I have to manually manage guards such as your `undefined` check and even rarer that I will modify a variable from a higher scope in a callback. I'm thinking there's some architecture change you can make to avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: I need thinking about this. What you say can make sense. I need to see if I can adapt legacy code to fit to this vision. Thanks for precising your idea.

Comment: I have an example. Let's have a page, on which there is a button. This button, once clicked, shows a dialog with one item to select amongst several others. At the loading of the page, you don't know it the button will be clicked, so you don't pre-load the items. When the users clicks on the button, you need to load the items. But maybe the button has already been clicked before, so that you don't have to reload the items (I suppose the items won't change between the two clicks). In this case, my pattern applies.

Comment: @GeirgeMauer That's great! As I'm not yet used to javascript dev, that's a tool I didn't know, and this solves this problematic of "Is my var already initialized?" I'll give it a try asap. Thank you for this alternative.

Comment: Thanks @RémiDoolaeghe yeah you'll find that doing things in a functional style in js is usually a much easier path than procedural, or even OO style. It makes sense, scheme is probably the language that influenced javascript more than any other (self was another big one, the fact that it kind-of looks like java was really just a marketing stunt by Netscape). I strongly recommend reading [Javascript the Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742), and [Javascript Allonge](https://leanpub.com/javascript-allonge/read) for an effective primer.

Answer (score 2):

If `myvar` is already defined you can pass that into `$.when()` and have it automatically wrapped into a resolved promise:

```
var def = (myVar !== undefined) ? myVar : loadMyVarAsynchronously();

$.when(def).then(doSomeTreatment);
```

Make the assignment to `myVar` inside `doSomeTreatment()`, if required, instead of inside the anonymous `.then` callback, this allows you to pass `doSomeTreatment` directly as a function reference.

**EDIT** oops, did you want standard Promises, or jQuery promises?  The above is jQuery style.

Comment: jQuery promises make me cry. How could the team [get them so very wrong](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)?

Comment: @Sukima because they standardized the API before A+ was a thing I believe.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I'm not sure it was before, but I do believe that jQuery's adoption of a Promise-_like_ API went a long way to promoting the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should build a promise for the value. Then you just need to attach that function only once as a handler:

```
var loadedMyVar = myvar!=undefined ? Promise.resolve(myvar) : loadMyVarAsynchronously();
loadedMyVar.then(doSomeTreatment);
```

Oh, and you shouldn't need to reassign to `myvar` asynchronously, just use the `loadedMyVar` promise everywhere. Maybe even use

```
var loadedMyVar = loadedMyVar || loadMyVarAsynchronously();
loadedMyVar.then(function(value) {
    return myvar = value;
}).then(doSomeTreatment);
```

Comment: I'll need to reassign myvar in my case, because I'm using two ways binding with Ractive, so I'll reassign in the asynchronous loading function

Comment: Meh ok, just make sure not to rely on that value for wether to call `loadMyVarAsynchronously()`, better directly look for the promise

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with using `myvar != undefined` as your check for whether to retrieve it, and that is that there may already be a retrieval in progress when you initiate another one. You'd wind up performing the request twice (or more!).

To avoid this, you can hold onto the promise, treating it as a *future value* for `myvar`, and not use `myvar` at all:

```
// assume myvarpromise is persisted somewhere longer than the 
// life of this function
myvarpromise = myvarpromise || loadMyVarAsynchronously();
myvarpromise.then(doSomeTreatment);
```

Comment: I had a doubt about it: consider a Promise that has already been resolved. Giving it a callback (with a call to then(...) ) will call it immediately.

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe When `.then()` is called on a promise that has already been resolved, the handler will be called asynchronously on Promises/A+-compliant promises, and immediately on jQuery promises and a few other kinds of promises.